# A word/phrase for something that does not do justice to something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

This system of evaluation is not doing justice to the employees' work. Those who are good are getting fewer scores, and those who are not good are getting higher scores. The system does not reveal good/bad traits in a fair, proper, or just way. It does not show the merits of the employees properly.

> This system is ------ .

nonfunctional? unfair? non-revealing?

Of course, unfair may work but it seems as there should be word that are more to the point for such circumstances.

Comment: It's *ineffective* in the sense it does not serve the intended purpose. However, there might, just might, be a better alternative. Let's see what the others have to say.

Comment: It might well be true, those who are good are getting fewer and those who are not good are getting higher scores. What evidence is there?

It might well be the system does not reveal good/bad traits in a fair, proper, or just way nor show the merits of employees properly.

This system is inadequate…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dysfunctional](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dysfunctional) is the first word in my mind, [edit] the old Oxford link has now been replaced with a simple definition, that has less merit :-) or as pointed out by @KnotWright below "Unmeritocratic"

There are many other words to describe something that's **unjust** or **meritless** , but trying to find an individuals connotation becomes more difficult. Demeaning is one word often applied, for when one is organisationally devalued.

The nearest I can suggest to injustice is to look at alternatives to **[iniquitous](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/iniquitous)** or **irrational** and for meritless we have **reasonless** or **unreasonable**

Looking at your wider context it is possibly best to say "This system **misjudges** the value of..." or "This system is **unprincipled**, because it is not guided by, or showing a concern for what is right"

Comment: I am looking for something that particularly means "not doing justice" or "not revealing merits".

Comment: Unmeritocratic is technically correct, but clunky and difficult.   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unmeritocratic

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for a *system*, you can use ***biased*** or ***skewed***. (There are other words more suited to *humans* like *prejudiced* or even *unfair*, for example).

> This (employee performance evaluation) system is ***biased***.
>   This (employee performance evaluation) system is ***skewed***.

ODO:

> **[biased](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/biased)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   Unfairly prejudiced for or against someone or something.
>
> ‘The charge that its review process is biased against right-wing
>   nominees is manifestly false.’
>
> **[skew](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/skew)**
>   *VERB*
>   **2** [with object] Make biased or distorted in a way that is regarded as inaccurate, unfair, or misleading.
>
> ‘The legal system is skewed towards mothers and, as a result, some
>   women abuse this for their own means, she claims.’